# How do I print numbers from small to big in python?

Tags: python-3.x, numbers

I have a homework about input some numbers and arrange from small to big.

The code here shows error and I'm not sure what it means and how to fix it

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Spyder Editor

This is a temporary script file.
"""

list1 = []
def disp_data():
    for items in datas:
        print(items,end=" ")
    print()
while True:
    h=input("input a number(press enter to exit):")
    if h == "":
        break
    else:
        datas = list1.append(h)
print('before:',end =" ")
disp_data()
n = len(datas)-1

for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n-i):
        if (datas[j]>datas[j+1]) :
            datas[j],datas[j+1]=datas[j+1],datas[j]

print("after:",end=" ")
disp_data()


TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I've already written one:

```
def disp_data():
    for items in datas:
        print(items,end=" ")
    print()

datas = [3,5,2,1]
print('before',end =" ")
disp_data()
n = len(datas)-1

for i in range(0,n):
    for j in range(0,n-i):
        if (datas[j]>datas[j+1]) :
            datas[j],datas[j+1]=datas[j+1],datas[j]

print("after",end=" ")
disp_data()
```

Any idea or bad grammar, please edit or answer it.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list methode `append` does return `None`, so `datas = list1.append(h)` makes datas `None`. A simple fix is to rename `list1` `datas`:

```
datas = []
```

[...]

```
while True:
    h = input("input a number(press enter to exit):")
    if h == "":
        break
    else:
        datas.append(h)
```